# How to differentiate in .htacces two urls after /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

How can I distinguish between 
www.xxx.com/aa/bb/cc
and 
www.xxx.com/aa/bb/

to differentiate into two RewriteRules ?

These RewriteRules don't work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?mode=cc&VarA=$1&VarB=$2&VarC=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?mode=bb&VarA=$1&VarB=$2 [L]
```

Thanks.

Comment: This is tagged as php because?

Comment: Use the one-or-more `+` quantifier instead of `*`.

Comment: I replaced the + by a * and it works !
Thank you :)

Final solution: 


RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]+)$ /index.php?m=produkt&category=$2&product=$3&language=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?m=kategorie&category=$2&language=$1 [L]